# ISPConfig Creating CNAME and A for web domain

Tags: cname-record

I have ISpConfig 3. I have an ip address **"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx".**    I want to configure this to point to `http://www.my.mydomain.com`

I have created DNS record and configured   **"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"**. and domain name `my.mydomain.com`

Problem is that **`my.mydomain.com`** is accessible through only   **`my.mydomain.com`** or through `http://my.mydomain.com` only.  i want that it should also be accessible through **`www.my.mydomain.com`**

Someone told me that i should have to create `CNAME` and `A` record for this domain. i have following Zone Record Configurations but this is not working. Please help me what i am doing wrong and what exactly should be CNAME and A configuration to work it with **`www.my.mydomain.com`**

**EDIT:**

In adding DNS zone. i just added    **my.mydomain.com** with IP   **xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx** 
so `my.mydomain.com`  is not normal subdomain

[image]

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the ending dot (.). All FCDNs have to end with one, so also your MX should be:

mail.my.mydomain.com.

// Edit: Forgot to mention. If you'd like to use it as a normal subdomain, you'd go good with creating it as a normal domain (like you added mydomain.com).

That's something I'm not that happy with how ISPConfig solves it...

So in general, your DNS should look something like:

> 1. A   mydomain.com.   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
> 2. A   www             xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
> 3. MX  mydomain.com.   mail.mydomain.com
> 4. NS  mydomain.com.   ns1.server.com
> 5. NS  mydomain.com.   ns2.server.com

(that would be for the "root" domain).

Now you would just have to add:

> 1. A   my              xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
> 2. A   www.my          xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

If you'd like to point my.domain.com to another domain, than CNAME would be the right choice, for example:

> CNAME   my          www.google.com.

Not sure if I understood the question correct, but this my help!

Comment: this did not worked. i dnt know what i am missing

Comment: So how did you add the domain mydomain.com? With the DNS wizard or by hand?

After that, did you add my as a subdomain? Or you did only add the DNS?

And do you wan't it to behave like a subdomain or just a "pointer"?

Answer (score 2):

You can just a add a CNAME. A CNAME points to another DNS name.

So you can add:

```
CNAME www.my.domain.com   my.domain.com
```

So now www.my.domain.com points to my.domain.com who points to x.x.x.x

my.domain.com must exist and point to either an A record or another CNAME.